How I can georeference a png image with GDAL in Django?
I am trying to georeference a png image with some control points, which would be the corner coordinates. I have achieved this using just GDAL with the following code:
from osgeo import gdal
 
ds = gdal.Open(f'{filename}.png')
gdal.Translate(filename + '.tif', ds, outputBounds=bounds)

But I can't put this in my Django API because Django GDAL doesn't have the gdal.Translate method. How can I georeference a png image with boundaries using Django/Django GDAL?

Maybe you can have more chance for a solution when asking in https://gis.stackexchange.com/
